Ubuntu 24.04 PXE boot + autoinstall failing to complete install
I created an iso using cubic with Ubuntu 24.04 server image. No modifications are done to the filesystem, it's all vanilla. I started with a working 22.04 autoinstall script and copied it to 24.04 image. I'm able to install from this 24.04 iso on a VM and a physical machine via USB. I'm not able to complete the install when using PXE boot on the same physical machine using the same iso and autoinstall as the USB install. I've made so many tweaks to the autoinstall in trying to fix it but I'm not able to finish the installer. I had a bare minimum autoinstall script, but it seems I have to put in there sections just so the installer continues, such as storage, networking. As before 22.04 I didn't have to put those in and the installer would use sane defaults.
If I run interactive installer as part of the autoinstall, the installer either freezes right away or soon after, usually around networking related functions.
Has anyone been successful in deploying 24.04 server via pxe boot on a physical machine? If so can you share your autoinstall and kernel boot config? Any ideas what I can try?
I'm able to deploy 22.04 via pxe boot to this machine.
